# Physical origin of the hydrodynamic instability?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory

I know that in plasma waves the kinetic instability is physically caused by more electrons moving slightly faster then the wave then slightly slow and thus proving energy to the wave. There is however a 'hydrodynamic instability' which may also appear. I can find derivations of such instabilities but am unsure of the underlying physical origin. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: Which instability? Raleigh-Taylor? Kelvin-Helmholtz? Another one?

Comment: @KyleKanos Ops sorry I didn't realize all of these would fall under the same category. I mean the one present when you consider a Maxwellian distribution with a Dirac delta peak in its tail - when solving the plasma dispersion relation.

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification - You mean a bump-on-tail or two-stream instability?